# Solana WebSocket URL Port doesn't shown on netstat

Tags: websocket, solana

I'd like to add WebSocket URL as:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8900
```

So I typed `solana config` get to get the location of `config.yaml` file. Then changed the WebSocket URL as followed above, however, after restarting the node and the server `http://0.0.0.0:8900` is not listed on `netstat -tulpn` . Do I have to do anything else or my node is unable to recognize the comfig.yaml file? Or do I have to pass additional parameter while starting the node? Any help appreciated thanks in advance.

Result of solana config get:

```
Config File: /home/centos/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://api.devnet.solana.com
WebSocket URL: http://0.0.0.0:8900
Keypair Path: /home/centos/solana/validator-keypair.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

It changes the WebSocket URL after I modify the config.yaml file but doesn't listed in netstat.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I started the node:

```
solana-validator \
  --ledger /home/centos/solana/data/ \
  --identity /home/centos/solana/validator-keypair.json \
  --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
  --rpc-port 8899 \
  --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
  --no-voting \
  --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
  --limit-ledger-size \
  --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
  --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
  --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
  --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
  --only-known-rpc \
  --no-port-check \
  --full-rpc-api
```

I did pass the port as 8899, so by default WS port should be 8900 right? I also changed the config.yml file to make it 0.0.0.0 in order to connect outside of the node. It's visible in netstat ports but I can connect to 8900 only locally.

```
Config File: /home/centos/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://0.0.0.0:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://0.0.0.0:8900
Keypair Path: /home/centos/validator-keypair.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

Answer (score 0):

`solana config get` only shows the client configuration, and not the node / validator configuration.

If you're using either `solana-validator` or `solana-test-validator`, you can set the rpc-port at the command line, and the websocket port will be right after:

```
$ solana-test-validator --rpc-port 10001
```

and somewhere else, you can see:

```
$ ss -l
<... truncated ...>
tcp     LISTEN   0        1024         0.0.0.0:10001      0.0.0.0:*
tcp     LISTEN   0        1024         0.0.0.0:10002      0.0.0.0:*
```

So the websocket port is `10002`.

To have the client connect to this validator, you can do:

```
solana config set -u http://localhost:10001
```